# Error discovered in an accepted conference paper but not yet presented

Tags: publications, errors-erratum, code

I'm a CS student, and I discovered two code bugs that change some numerical values on a table of a paper that got accepted and will be presented at a conference very soon. The changes is very small (think 0.1), and they don't affect the main conclusions of the paper at all.

I haven't talked to my coauthors yet but I don't know how to go about this. On the one hand I'm scared if I contact the organizers they might retract it for not being super accurate or something like that (conclusions don't get affected at all), but on the other hand I don't want to publish buggy code on GitHub and get caught there. What is the best way to go about this? Will the retract the paper if I contact the organizers?

Comment: Have you submitted a camera-ready paper yet? If not, then just modify the paper before you do.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your co-authors of course. But also talk to the conference committee and provide, or offer to provide, corrected copy. They may be able to help or not. But for the presentation, give the latest, most correct, version and note, if necessary, that the printed version has small errors not affecting the conclusions.

Some CS conferences will print proceedings and some of them will have a version ready before the conference. It may be possible that a second version, for general distribution, can differ a bit in details, but that is up to the conference and to the publication board of the organization sponsoring the conference.

But letting everyone know immediately is the best overall strategy.